# insert data and sum as well in my sql

Tags: mysql

maybe the subject is not precise

but i have a problem how to insert a data into a table and also calculate them.

i have a table

```
no   date         product_code   first_stok   in   out  final_stock
1    2018/01/18      A001          50          0   0      50
2    2018/01/18      A001          0           0   35     15 <==== i want to achieve this
```

when I insert a new data (data no 2 ) and fill column "out" with 35, the "final_stock" column will have 15. how can I achieve that

this is my query

```
mysql_query("insert into flow_stock (date, product_code, first_stok, in, out, final_stock )
                    values('$date', '$code','','','$out','')");
mysql_query("update flow_stock set final_stok = final_stok-'$out'
                    where product_code ='$code'");
```

need your help

Comment: And what is the problem? Is the second row inserted or not?

Comment: if I inserted like 2nd row the final_stock will be 15

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
mysql_query("insert into flow_stock (date, product_code, first_stok, in, out, final_stock )
values('$date', '$code','','','$out',(select final_stock from flow_stock order by no desc limit 1) - ".$out.")");
```

Comment: i'll try it and let you know the result