# how to calculate a value of the last row with a new inserted value in mysql

Tags: mysql

All

how to calculate a value of the last row with a  new inserted value in mysql

final_stock (2nd) row = final_stock(1st) row - out(2nd) row

i have a table

```
no   date         product_code   first_stock   in  out  final_stock
1    2018/01/18      A001          50          0   0      50 (last inserted)
2    2018/01/18      A001          0           0   35     15 <==== i want to achieve this
```

when I insert a new data (data no 2 ) and fill column "out" with 35, the "final_stock" column in 2nd row will have 15. how can I achieve that

this is the query

```
mysql_query("insert into flow_stock (date, product_code, first_stock, in, out, final_stock )
values('$date', '$code','','','$out',(select final_stock from flow_stock order by no desc limit 1) - ".$out.")");
```

need your help, the query doesn't calculate

Comment: Please stop using PHP's ancient, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert data and sum as well in my sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377411/insert-data-and-sum-as-well-in-my-sql)

Comment: that's of insert data and sum as well in my sql is also mine,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,date DATE NOT NULL
,product_code CHAR(4) NOT NULL
,first_stock INT NOT NULL
,`in` INT NOT NULL
,`out` INT NOT NULL
,final_stock INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,'2018-01-18','A001',50,0,0,50);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
| no | date       | product_code | first_stock | in | out | final_stock |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
|  1 | 2018-01-18 | A001         |          50 |  0 |   0 |          50 |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+----+-----+-------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (date,product_code,first_stock,`in`,`out`,final_stock) 
SELECT '2018-01-21'
     , 'A001'
     , 0
     , 0
     , 35
     , final_stock - 35 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE product_code = 'A001' 
 ORDER 
    BY no DESC 
 LIMIT 1;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
| no | date       | product_code | first_stock | in | out | final_stock |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
|  1 | 2018-01-18 | A001         |          50 |  0 |   0 |          50 |
|  2 | 2018-01-21 | A001         |           0 |  0 |  35 |          15 |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: it works, suppeeerrbbb,  thank you very much @Strawberry